# Can anyone explain me how i can do url rewriting

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a forum in which people having their account and i don't seem to understand this concept.

After we created the file named after the user, do we create a new PHP file and write all the codes in it or is it something else.

I can't understand it quite nicely.

Comment: Most of the time it's a combination of `$_GET` and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you want is a combination of a database and URL rewriting.

**Database**

Databases are used for storing large amounts of data. You can get and put things into the database from PHP, if you're using a database like [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com). (this is probably the easiest one to learn) There are many guides available on connecting to databases and getting and putting data into it. What you solve with this is that you do not need to have a PHP file for every user, you only need one and in it, you're not storing any of the data from the user, you are only interacting with the database.

A quick Google search should pop-up thousands of guides on how to connect with a MySQL database. Please make sure you are following a guide that uses MySQLi or PDO, two drivers that are a lot better than the standard MySQL driver. (you will see the difference in the functions, with MySQLi you would have functions called `mysqli_connect()`. The reason I'm saying this is that the MySQL driver is deprecated in the latest versions of PHP, and it has a few security issues that can easily be avoided with MySQLi or PDO.

**URL rewriting**

To have your URLs be as easy as `http://www.example.com/user/deniz_zoeteman`, or even `http://www.example.com/deniz_zoeteman`, you need to make URL rewrites. Now this largely depends on what web server you are using, but if you are with a hosting company, good chance it's going to be Apache. You can use an example like this one in the config files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

There are many guides on URL rewriting available too, an example is [this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) one. If you use the example above, you can get the username that was put in the URL in PHP like this:

```
$username = $_GET['user'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a `database`. You won't need to write a php file for each user, but instead a single php file that fetch the desired informations from the database and displays them.

Remember, every time that you're duplicating code, something is deeply wrong and you should take a step back and find a better solution. A database allows you to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Using `mod_rewrite` in either a Virtual Host, or .htaccess file, you can do something like;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Which would rewrite http://abcde.com/index.php?page=aviyankhadka to http://abcde.com/aviyankhadka

To help generate the `RewriteRule`, have a look [here](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/)

This answer assumes you're routing requests through the index file, by the way.